# Get unique values from an array of objects using Cofeescript

Tags: coffeescript, unique

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Paul",
    "parent": "Jane"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Paul",
    "parent": "Jack"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mike",
    "parent": "Janice"
  },
]
```

And every time the parent value is repeated I would like to show only the first element, like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Paul",
    "parent": "Jane"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mike",
    "parent": "Janice"
  },
]
```

How can I accomplish this using cofeescript? Thank you so much!

Comment: "every time the parent value is repeated I would like to show only the first element"

That's not what your example shows. 

I think you probably mean "I only want to show the first occurrence of element with a given `name`". I.e., "I want to filter out elements with a duplicate `name` attribute (after the first occurrence)". 

Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Hi not sure regarding cofeescript, but in typescript this would work:

```
/**
* usage example:
* var items = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 2},{id: 3}];
* var test = uniqueArray(items);
* @param items []
*/
export function uniqueArray<T>(items: T[]): T[] {
  return [...new Map(items.map((item: any) => [item['name'], item])).values()];
}
```

Again not sure how coffeescript works with their Map function but, maybe there is a semilliar way of work in coffee-script. If not .... you can ignore this :P